# Prevent Word online from remapping Command-M in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: ms-office, google-chrome, shortcut, firefox

I quite frequently use the Command-M shortcut to minimise windows, however I have found that when editing an online Microsoft Word document in Chrome or Firefox, the Command-M shortcut is somehow remapped to indent the current line instead of minimising the window.

Is there a way to prevent that behaviour (ideally specifically for just that one shortcut)?

Aside: Why does Word Online want to do that anyway? - The Mac desktop Word app doesn't indent with Command-M or Control-M so at a glance it doesn't seem to be replicating desktop app behaviour

Comment: Perhaps you could make a key shortcut specific to Chrome and Firefox in System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > App shortcuts, and set the Minimise Window keyboard shortcut to something other than command+M?

Comment: I guess I could, but it's very much muscle memory for me that it's command-m, so I'd prefer a solution which doesn't require me leaning a new shortcut. 10 times a day I hit it on a browser window and get annoyed that it didn't do what I expected 